# ERROR: Cannot install PyCharm: No JRE found

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install PyCharm on my raspberry-pi 4 but I get this error:

> `ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm: No JDK found`

and I also tried:

`sudo apt install default-jre`

but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: `sudo apt install default-jdk`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The JRE is a subset of the JDK](https://cdn.guru99.com/images/2/022220_0635_JDKvsJREvsJ1.png). It's possible that you need the whole JDK in order for PyCharm to work.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

if openjdk-11-jdk is already installed, you need to run:

```
export PYCHARM_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
```

this will add the address of the jdk to the correct environment variable.